# Storing associated variables

Tags: struct, swift4, grouping

I have around 30 api's in my application and each api url has associated custom error code and error message . For now, I have them all in constants , ungrouped. What is the best way to group them.. like to use structs? or enums? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

```
class ApplicationAPIS {
 My_API1 {
 static let API_URL = "http:www.google.com"
 static let API_CODE = "ER0012"
 static let API_ERROR_MSG = "Cannot Load URL" }

 My_API2{
 static let API_URL = "http:www.google.com"
 static let API_CODE = "ER0012"
 static let API_ERROR_MSG = "Cannot Load URL" }

 .
 .
 .
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual thing for constant strings (such as keys into UserDefaults, etc.) is a struct with static constant properties. For example:

```
struct My_API1 {
    static let API_URL = "http:www.google.com"
    static let API_CODE = "ER0012"
    static let API_ERROR_MSG = "Cannot Load URL" 
}
```

Now you can speak of e.g. `My_API1.API_URL` from anywhere in your program.

However, if these really are always errors, then you might be happier making these the cases of an enum that conforms to the Error type.

```
enum My_API1 : String, Error {
    case API_URL = "http:www.google.com"
    case API_CODE = "ER0012"
    case API_ERROR_MSG = "Cannot Load URL" 
}
```